# Is $G $ contained in $ G *_H K $ if $ H\rightarrow G $ and $ H\rightarrow K$ are injections?

Tags: group-theory

Given injections $ H\rightarrow G $ and $ H\rightarrow K $, is the canonical morphism $ G\rightarrow  G *_H K $ of G into the free product with amalgamation also injective?

Comment: Yes. It is injective by definition if you use the reduced words definition.

Comment: "Reduced words" is the worst definition of amalgamted sums I can think of. Amalgamated sums aka pushouts are defined via universal properties, and actually for groups the description of the elements via reduced words can be derived from the universal property (as explained in Serre's *Trees*).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, ""Reduced words" is the worst definition of amalgamted sums I can think of." Well, you're not being very creative then.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg :Just as with free groups, it is the existence of the amalgamated sum which takes most work. Once you have existence, I agree that the universal property takes care of pretty much everything else.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, My favorite way of doing this (maybe yours too?) is to define these things via the universal property, show they exist using the appropriate equivalence relation on words, and then use the universal property to prove that each equivalence class contains a unique "reduced" representative. Each description (via universal properties and via reduced words) has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Steve : Mine too. I think Serre does that. I agree with your last statement.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, if you think that the universal property is a universally useful way to think about this, I invite you to pick a good book on combinatorial group theory and try to prove any significant theorem there using it :-) Proficiency in the manipulation of reduced words and such nasty stuff is essential to pretty much anything, so a definition which up front trains you to deal with this stuff cannot be that bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since every element $x\in G_1 *_H G_2$ has a (unique) canonical form 
$x=ab_1\ldots b_r$ where $a\in H, b_i\in  G_1$ or $b_i\in G_2$, $b_i$ are coset representatives of $G_j$'s by $H$, and  $b_i,b_{i+1}$ ($i\le r-1$) belong to different  $G_j$'s. See M.Hall, The Theory of groups, Theorem 17.2.1.

Comment: But $a$ is not unique, only unique modulo $H$. I think we need the full reduced form here, involving iterated products between elements of $G$ and $K$.

Comment: I also don't understand: even (especially!) if $H=1$, in which case we get the free product and not every element is of the form $ac$ with $a \in G$ and $b \in K$.

Comment: @ Steve : Sorry, it was too late yesterday when I wrote. I corrected the answer.

Comment: @ Geoff Robinson : Sorry, it was too late yesterday when I wrote. I corrected the answer.

Comment: @ Martin Brandenburg :Sorry, it was too late yesterday when I wrote. I corrected the answer.